# SharePoint 2010 Search Refinement Panel

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-search

Can anyone please help me in understanding  count values in SharePoint refinement panel.
In my environment when I am searching for some keyword say "**abc**" then in refinement panel it is showing some filter category say "**filter1(6)**", what I understand in this case is that there are 6 results with "**filter1**" category and "**abc**" keyword, but if now I select "**filter1(6)**" category from the refinement panel it shows me "**filter1(8)**" and lists all the 8 documents. I look around many times in the search results and found that there is 1 duplicate result when filtering with category "**filter1**", even then the count values are not correct or I am not understanding the concept hows SharePoint set count values.
I have also tried setting the accuracy index value to 50 and 100, and there are 50 results in my result set.
I am confused now hows SharePoint showing count values?? why it shown count value earlier 6 when there are 8 results with the "**filter1**" category.

Comment: Did you get any answer for your own?

Comment: Hav't find any solution yet. :( :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem in the project I was working 2 months ago.

We were working with FAST For Sharepoint 2010 and I read that Sharepoint Search doesn't have the functionality to give the count on refiners as the exact number.

In FAST, you have to create the managed property with the 'Deep refiner' property checked, to make the service give the total count in the refiner parameter.

See you! I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi Amedio, is this issue also with enterprise search as we were working on this? we are using show count property of metadata properties in refinement panel under Refinement > Filter category definition? Do we need to create some new property ? I can't see how to create deep refiner propery?

Comment: The thing is that I think the property for Managed properties, 'Deep refiner' is just part of FAST for Sharepoint 2010, so I think you won't see the property, as I pointed in my explanation. Sorry I can't help you more, I'm too new :)

Comment: Yes Amedio I looked for the deep refiner option in my properties but hav't found it there. anyways thanks for your rplies :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help explain it.

http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-search-refinement-panel-options/

Look at the section titled **Accuracy Index**.

> The accuracy index number is the number of results used to calculate
> the refiner counts. Now this is usually not turned on in default
> SharePoint 2010 search (however it can be) and if the number is lower
> than the total result set then you might get false numbers returned
> for refiners. Lets say that we have the Accuracy Index set to 50 and
> the total result set is 250. . . .
>
> Hmm users will look at the total results (250) and then see that only
> 21 word documents and 13 web pages were part of 250 results? Hmm that
> doesn’t make sense. Well actually it does. The calculations are based
> not on the result set but rather the number of results specified in
> the Accuracy Index. So for 50 it does make sense. If we change the
> Accuracy Index to 300 we get a much more logical refiner count appear:
>
> But be careful, calculating refiners does take some CPU power so try not to set it to 10,000 so that every single search always calculates refiners, try to find a balance.

In summary, Accuracy Index is a property on the refinement panel web part that tells how many items are used from the results to calculate the *estimated* refiner counts.

Comment: Hi @Dan, welcome to SO! Please quote the section you're talking about in your answer, just in case the site you're linking to disappears one day.